# Is returning the same geolocation to different addresses, how to solve?

Tags: here-api

**The only difference between the two addresses is the number(housenumber).**

**Request_1:**
*https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&countryfocus=BRA&country=BRA&street=AVENIDA VEREADOR EDENITES DA SILVA VIANA&**housenumber=244**&city=São Francisco de Itabapoana&district=CENTRO&postalcode=28230000&state=RJ*
**Response_1**: -21.47765, -41.10775

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Request_2:**
*https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&countryfocus=BRA&country=BRA&street=AVENIDA VEREADOR EDENITES DA SILVA VIANA&**housenumber=160**&city=São Francisco de Itabapoana&district=CENTRO&postalcode=28230000&state=RJ*
**Response_2**: -21.47765, -41.10775

**help, please**

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind same location position in response is because the **matchLevel** in your request is **street** so it doesn't matter if you will change the house number in the request, the position will point to the street address every time until it will find a housenumber/name.

```
"Result": [
                {
                    "Relevance": 0.9,
                    "MatchLevel": "street",----> street is matched in response
                    "MatchQuality": {
                        "Country": 1.0,
                        "City": 1.0,
                        "Street": [
                            0.9
                        ]
                    },
```

In the match quality there is no where it says **hosuenumber**  like below response from the [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-partial-address.)-

```
"Result": [
      {
        "Relevance": 1,
        "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
        "MatchQuality": {
          "Country": 1,
          "City": 1,
          "Street": [
            0.85
          ],
          "HouseNumber": 1
        },
```

To resolve this please enter the valid housenumber which matches this search.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-partial-address